# m key not registering in Bourne-Again shell 3.2, OSX. Guesses?

Tags: bash, shell, keyboard-layout

Just lowercase `m`, and just when invoked interactively through `/bin/sh`.
The keyboard works fine, and usually everything works fine. I almost never use `/bin/sh`, just `/bin/bash`, so it was somewhat surprising when I fired up sh on a whim just now.

Bash, not Bourne shell, since I guess sh is just a link to `bash` in OSX, too...
But regardless it's odd. Bash version 3.2.48(1).

My `~/.inputrc` doesn't contain anything odd, and neither does `~/.profile`, or `/etc/profile`, but I'm guessing at some point months ago I modified a config file to make this happen. Either that or something legitimately screwy is up.

I know `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc` aren't being run (because they print things and modify environment variables in a very distinctive way).

Whatever the case, it bugs me. Any guesses where else I should look?

edit: On restarting the machine, I'm having the problem invoked both invoked as `/bin/bash` and as `/bin/sh`. Invoking bash with --norc doesn't change the odd behavior, which leads me to believe something system-level has been modified distastefully.

`m` is not currently an alias for anything (`type m` brings up nothing) and I can still run commands involving `m` by creating a temporary script file and then sourcing it.

xev (and basically every other program) confirms that the issue is not with the m keypress event at the kernel or hardware level.

Comment: Your `m` is mapped to something. Is there something when you type `alias`? Do you have the `xev` installed?

Comment: @ott-- I do have xev. Had too look it up, though. And there are no aliases defined- although I don't know how an alias could affect readline behavior.

Comment: So what is xev reporting for your `m`?

Comment: @ott-- It registers the keypress event correctly regardless of shell invocation (`/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash`). When I type `m` on the command line from the shell it doesn't print, though, nor does it actually record (without printing) or be remapped to a printing character (which includes backspace- I tried `lsm` `<Enter>` and it ran `ls`).

Comment: @ott-- However, running `set -o vi` caused it to start rendering `m` normally, which definitely points to a scripted remapping...

Comment: Does `Ctrl+V m` insert an `m`? Does uppercase `M` work? What does `bind -p | grep $'^"\155"'` show?

Comment: Try the command `type m`.

Comment: @Gilles (1) No (2) Yes (3) Nothing

Comment: Try running Bash like this: `INPUTRC=/dev/null bash --noprofile --norc`

Comment: @EvanTeitelman I ran `env INPUTRC=/dev/null bash --noprofile --norc` and `m` registers correctly in this subshell. Since it worked, I ran `. ~/.bashrc`, and `m` still works fine. And I tried `. /etc/profile` and `. /etc/bashrc`. Still, `m` works fine. And yet when I shut down `Terminal` and restart it, it doesn't work.

Comment: It looks like it's your terminal that's eating the `m` and not the shell. What terminal are you using? If you run `cat` and type `m`, does it show? If you run a full-screen text mode program (`emacs -nw`, `vim`, whatever floats your boat), does the `m` do something (if not: in Emacs, try `Ctrl+C Ctrl+H m`)? If you run bash in another terminal emulator, does `m` work?

Comment: @EvanTeitelman _However_, when I run `bash` from within the working subshell, it works. Which means it only needed INPUTRC to be /dev/null...

Comment: Wait... I just realized what it is. In my `~/.inputrc`, I added `editing_mode (vi)` early on yesterday to make programs relying on readline let me use vi-style keybindings.

Answer (score 3):

In my `~/.inputrc`, I added `editing_mode (vi)` early on yesterday to make programs relying on readline let me use vi-style keybindings. Sorry I didn't mention that; it didn't even register as a possible cause because I still can't see why that would screw things up, but it did.

It might have screwed things up because I also have `set -o vi` in my `~/.bashrc` but ultimately I have no idea. All I know is commenting out that line fixed it.